# How to access custom line item field in rules loop?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I'm trying to perform an action on checkout for each line item in an order (fetched with Rules loop).
The action should set value to custom line item fields.

The problem is that those fields are not available in the list of tokens when I choose `Set a data value`. I tried accessing them but Rules won't let me save the data selector.

Any ideas on how can I access custom fields for line items?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added a "entity has field" condition for your custom field?

Comment: Thanks for quick message. I tried with that as well; I set the condition that first item (`0`) has my custom field, but it didn't appear in token list for actions.